# An error thrown in the official nuget sdk example code

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

```
ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;
CancellationToken cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;

SourceCacheContext cache = new SourceCacheContext();
SourceRepository repository = Repository.Factory.GetCoreV3("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
PackageMetadataResource resource = await repository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();

IEnumerable<IPackageSearchMetadata> packages = await resource.GetMetadataAsync(
    "Newtonsoft.Json",
    includePrerelease: true,
    includeUnlisted: false,
    cache,
    logger,
    cancellationToken);

foreach (IPackageSearchMetadata package in packages)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Version: {package.Identity.Version}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Listed: {package.IsListed}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Tags: {package.Tags}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Description: {package.Description}");
}
```

This code is written in C#. The logger attribute inside the `IEnumerable` throws an error. Also, and more important it gets stuck on the first line of code with `await`:

```
PackageMetadataResource resource = await repository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();
```

It gets there, but the await never closes.

Does anyone knows how to fix this? Did anyone have this problem before?

This is the official SDK link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk

I want to solve the problems so it does not get stuck and returns the expected example output

Comment: "The logger atribute inside the IEnumerable throws an error." I don't understand what you mean - and you haven't given *any* information about what kind of error this is. (Compile-time? Exception? What's the error?)

Comment: Cannot convert from 'NuGet.ILogger' to 'NuGet.Common.ILogger'

Comment: I just tested the sample and it works, i guess you messed up the usings for the logger.

Comment: It does actually print the example?

Comment: So it's a compilation error - although your wording of "logger atribute inside the IEnumerable" is still *really* unclear. Please edit your question to clarify the nature of the error, exactly where it occurs, and what the error is. (Comments shouldn't be used for crucial information like this.) It does sound like you've just got the wrong using directives though.

Answer (score 0):

works as expected for me

```
using NuGet.Common;
using NuGet.Protocol;
using NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types;

namespace ConsoleApp20
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;

            SourceCacheContext cache = new SourceCacheContext();
            SourceRepository repository = Repository.Factory.GetCoreV3("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
            PackageMetadataResource resource = await repository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();

            IEnumerable<IPackageSearchMetadata> packages = await resource.GetMetadataAsync(
                "Newtonsoft.Json",
                includePrerelease: true,
                includeUnlisted: false,
                cache,
                logger,
                cancellationToken);

            foreach (IPackageSearchMetadata package in packages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Version: {package.Identity.Version}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Listed: {package.IsListed}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Tags: {package.Tags}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Description: {package.Description}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sample output (incomplete):

```
Description: Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET
Version: 4.5.3
Listed: True
Tags: json
```

Comment: The logger problem solved. it stills does not seem to execute code past "PackageMetadataResource resource = await repository.GetResourceAsync();" Any possible solution?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: no error, it just keeps waiting until infinity

Comment: i guess the problem is related to your environment not to the code. That's kinda hard to answer without further information. Maybe it's a network problem on your side. Since the code work's on my machine the server seems to be fine.

Comment: Okay i will see what happens in the proyecy

Comment: flat out does not work. Just hangs never returns